# error when i bind combobox with database column?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

when i want to bind a combobox with a table column i have error like image in the link
this is image link http://s23.postimg.org/btzj2n66j/Capture.png ------ and this is my code

```
private void bindcombo ()
    {
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        com.Connection = db_con;
        db_con.Open();
        com.CommandText = "select * from colleges";
        reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            string combo_items = reader.GetString("college_name");
            college_name.Items.Add(combo_items);//college_name is a combobox
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the GetString() method accepts only int as the parameter, you're trying to use a string.
Hat's so doubtfull about that?